# What do functional programmers mean by "moral"?

Tags: functional-programming, terminology

I've noticed the word "moral" keeps coming up in functional programming contexts. A couple examples:

- [*Fast and Loose Reasoning is Morally Correct*](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/publications/danielsson-et-al-popl2006.html)
- Purescript [`Aff`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-aff/0.16.1/docs/Control.Monad.Aff#t:Aff) documentation:

  > This is moral equivalent of `ErrorT (ContT Unit (Eff e)) a`.

I'm unfamiliar with these usages of the word. I can mostly infer what they're trying to say, but can we clarify more precisely what it means?

(Cross-posted on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/331414/can-morally-mean-approximately))

Comment: This seems more like a [programmers.se] question.

Comment: FWIW, just drop the "moral" and the sense stays the same. IMO, all this "moral-ness" is just a FP fad; see http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Moral_equivalence etc.

Comment: "Moral equivalence" can be thought of more or less as the same principle that duck-typing follows... If it walks like a duck, talks like a duck and quacks like a duck, then it must be a duck.  It's another way of saying "as long as the end result is the same (I get the same output given a specific input), I don't really care what happens under the hood."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about the English language, not programming - this terminology is not restricted to functional programming. You might have more luck at [english.SE].

Comment: @Bergi As you can see in the answers, the term _moral_ has a specific meaning in mathematics/programming.

Comment: @larsrh: I think "morally equivalent" means just the same in maths/FP as [elsewhere](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/331424): not strictly true based on all the laws and rules, but believed to be true or close enough to the truth for practical purposes. That's pretty much what your answer says, isn't it?

Answer (score 8):

The term "moral equivalence" in (formalized) logics, and by extension, in programming has nothing to do with appeal to morality (as in, ethical or philosophical questions). It is co-opting the term "morally", but means something different. It is generally supposed to mean "P holds, but only under certain side-conditions". These conditions are often omitted if they have no educational value, are trivial, technical and/or boring. Hence, the linked article about "moral equivalence" has nothing to do it – there are no value judgements involved here.

I don't know much about Purescript, but the way I'd interpret the statement you mentioned as "you can achieve the same thing with `Aff` as `ErrorT (ContT Unit (Eff e)) a`."

To give another example: Let's say you have two functions and you are only interested in a specific (maybe large) subset of their domains. Let's also say that these two functions agree on these domains, that is, for all x ∈ dom, f(x) = g(x). But for the sake of the example, maybe they do something different on 0, but you will not ever pass 0 into them (because 0 violates some assumption). One could reasonably say that f and g "are morally equivalent".

Especially in the logics community, there are other uses of "moral", for example in the phrase "the proof is morally questionable", which means that the author considers the proof to be sloppy and that it may have gaps, but technically fixable. In a particular case, namely carrying out proofs about potentially non-terminating programs, the paper you have mentioned gives such a justification, which is echoed in the title "Fast and Loose Reasoning is Morally Correct."

Answer (score 2):

As Conor McBride points out on twitter, this usage stems from the category theory community, which inspires much in fp.

https://twitter.com/pigworker/status/739971825128607744

Eugenia Cheng has a good paper describing the concept of morality as used in mathematics.

http://www.cheng.staff.shef.ac.uk/morality/morality.pdf